# Upgrading ReactionCommerce from 1.4.x to 1.5.x gives ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/folder/@reactioncommerce'

Tags: reactjs, meteor

Upgrading from Reaction Commerce 1.4.x to 1.5.x I received this error on `rc run`

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/mikeumus/rc-ca-blinds/@reactioncommerce' 

If you notice problems related to these missing modules, consider running:

  meteor npm install --save @reactioncommerce
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Babel `module_resolver` alias not working in `package.json`. 
I resolved the issue by listening to the output messages the RC cli was giving to install missing npm moldues. Not installing `@reactioncommerce` (as in this case that's the babel module alias that's not working) but the other modules.

---

@spencern from the Reaction Commerce Gitter.im also says:

> I’ve seen it specifically when you have a package.json file in a plugin, but I think it may happen in other scenarios sometimes as well. Glad you got it working.

https://gitter.im/reactioncommerce/reaction?at=59f3678bf7299e8f533da3ea

---

@josx from Reaction Commerce Gitter.im says this about the issue:

> Aliases wont work in your custom plugin if you have dependencies, check this issue [reactioncommerce/reaction#3178](https://github.com/reactioncommerce/reaction/issues/3178)

https://gitter.im/reactioncommerce/reaction?at=59f3ef80e44c43700a88f81e